# Изменение языка отладки Visual C++

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

Можно ли сменить язык компилятора VC на английский (сейчас русский)? Использую его в Qt, а так как я загрузил версию 5.6, исправленный jom.exe найти проблематично.

Comment: как вариант можно его [скачать](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41151) и установить

Comment: Если это единственный вариант, то ладно. Но хотелось бы не засорять компьютер копиями одного и того же

Comment: @YuriyOrlov Вопрос не праздный, пожалуйста опубликуйте свой коментарий как ответ.

Comment: @Cerbo, я не считаю, что комментарий из половины предложения можно считать ответом.

Comment: @YuriyOrlov Естественно, нужно и на словах пояснить.